# Parsing web service response with SimpleXML fails

Tags: php, xml, web-services, curl, simplexml

I am calling a weather web service and I do get a response but I do not manage to read one element from the response.

The response looks like this:

```
<string xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <CurrentWeather>
        <Location>Hamburg-Finkenwerder,Germany (EDHI) 53-32N 009-50E 13M</Location> 
        <Time>Sep 28, 2013 - 03:35 AM EDT / 2013.09.28 0735 UTC</Time>
        <Wind> Variable at 1 MPH (1 KT):0</Wind>
        <Visibility> less than 1 mile:0</Visibility>
        <SkyConditions> mostly cloudy</SkyConditions>
        <Temperature> 44 F (7 C)</Temperature>
        <DewPoint> 44 F (7 C)</DewPoint>
        <RelativeHumidity> 100%</RelativeHumidity>
        <Pressure> 30.03 in. Hg (1017 hPa)</Pressure>
        <Status>Success</Status>
    </CurrentWeather>
</string>
```

My code looks like this:

```
$url = "http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx/GetWeather?CityName=Hamburg&CountryName=Germany";

$options = array (CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, // return web page
CURLOPT_HEADER => false, // don't return headers
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true, // follow redirects
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "xml", // handle compressed
CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "test", // who am i
CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true, // set referer on redirect
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120, // timeout on connect
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120, // timeout on response
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10 ); // stop after 10 redirects

$ch = curl_init ( $url );
curl_setopt_array ( $ch, $options );
$response = curl_exec ( $ch );
$err = curl_errno ( $ch );
$errmsg = curl_error ( $ch );
$header = curl_getinfo ( $ch );
$httpCode = curl_getinfo ( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );

curl_close ( $ch );

$xml = json_decode(json_encode((array) simplexml_load_string($response)), 1);
print_r($xml->SkyConditions);
```

Basically, I would like to read the element value of SkyConditions.

`$xml->SkyConditions` returns "" as well as `$xml[0]->SkyConditions`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You defined `$sUrl` and are trying to use `$url` further below.

Comment: What is the JSON encoding and decoding? And the array casting? You should just be able to load that string on its own, and get an element object back.

Comment: @Amal: Corrected my copy and paste typo. This is not the issue here.

Comment: @halfer: I just fiddled around with sinplexml_load_string. Basically, when I try to parse the xml, I never find any elements.

Comment: When I use "$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);" I do get: "SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Heidelberg, Germany (ETIE) 49-24N 008-39E 109M Jun 14, 2013 - 06:55 PM EDT / 2013.06.14 2255 UTC from the E (100 degrees) at 8 MPH (7 KT):0 greater than 7 mile(s):0 partly cloudy 62.4 F (16.9 C) 47.3 F (8.5 C) 57% 30 in. Hg (1015 hPa) Success )" , which means that all node or element tags are gone. I assume that this is the reason why I cannot access one.

Comment: Are you sure you've reproduced the XML correctly? The `<?xml` preamble should be the first thing you see, and before the `<string>` element.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I searched more and found the comment that this web service simply does not return a useful xml response. I am using the yahoo service now and this works like charm.

Thanks anyway!